# Trying to understand about Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

Java Syntax's of generic classes and methods were not added until 5.0 of Java. But early versions of Java had collections classes such as an array list, or a linked list. how were classes implemented and used without the generic syntax. Why are syntax of generics better?

Comment: I suppose they accepted Object's objects. Since all classes derive from Object, thanks to polymorphism, we can store a reference to a specific object in a more general variable, which in this case would be a variable of type Object. Of course, I have not talked 100% precisely, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Generics a type-safe. Developers of the language saved raw types to save backward compatibility, but it's deprecated and not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without generics, every item would be stored in a collection as an 'Object', the base class of all Java objects. That means re-casting them when you get them back out of the collection. Re-casting means you have to be certain of what type they are, and that leaves you open to dangerous mistakes. With generics, you can permanently keep a record of the class/type of objects you are storing in your collection, so that when they come out, they are still represented as objects of that class. No more type casting problems.

Comment: so its all just a way to avoid re-casting?

Answer (score 0):

Generics provide type safety. For example, if you have `ArrayList<String>` you know that it can only hold strings. However if you have just a `List` as a raw type, it is possible to add different types of objects to it and this could cause ClassCastExceptions at runtime while retrieving items from the list.

For a full explanation of why you should always use generics instead of raw types, see the chapter on Generics in Effective Java, specifically "Item 23: Don't use raw types in new code": http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf

Comment: having trouble downloading the PDF

Comment: Im using Chrome and it is downloading fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Why Use Generics?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) at the Java Tutorials for a good justification.

**In summary**

- Stronger type checks at compile time;
- Eliminates casts;
- Enables programmers to implement generic algorithms and thus reuse more code.